# Python Pillow image quality different in linux

Tags: python, ubuntu, image-processing, selenium-webdriver, python-imaging-library

I have a bot that plays an online game that is driven by selenium. It works by utilizing image recognition (finding subimages). In Windows, my bot works fine; however, my bot does not work in Ubuntu.

The bot works like this:

1. takes a screenshot of an element in selenium
2. uses pillow to load the screenshot
3. finds a subimage (a local image) in the larger screenshot

I've traced the issue to the function I'm using to find a subimage. It doesn't work because the screenshot image quality is different on Ubuntu, and it can't do a pixel by pixel match.

A working needle and haystack image set from Windows works fine on Ubuntu, and the inverse is also true -- a non-working needle and haystack image set created from Ubuntu does not work on both Windows and Ubuntu.

My screenshot is always ~6KB in Windows and ~5KB in Ubuntu.

When I open my local "needle" image in PIL and save it, it goes from 1.7KB to 1.5KB and doesn't work as a result. This is the non 500 line version of the code:

```
# imports and everything else here..

browser.save_screenshot("haystack.png") # selenium screenshot
haystack = Image.open("haystack.png")
needle = Image.open("needle.png") # the needle is a local file

haystack.save("haystack_new.png","PNG",quality=100) # DEBUGGING
needle.save("needle_new.png","PNG",quality=100) # DEBUGGING

# call "needle in a haystack" locator function here
```

Can someone tell me what's going wrong? Why are the linux screenshots lower quality? Should I install a different version of zlib or just use opencv instead?

Comment: Are the haystack screenshot files the same pixel dimensions between Ubuntu and Windows?

Comment: Yup. The haystack is 250x75 on both platforms

Comment: PNG is lossless (the 'quality=' determines how much time is spent compressing it losslessly), so something else lossy must be happening. A good candidate would be if the ubuntu image uses a colour palette (perhaps because the ubuntu display is 256-colour). Look at the metadata for the haystack images, are they both the same e.g. 24-bit, or is one 256-colour? Also compare the metadata of the original Windows haystack with the version saved from PIL/pillow.

Comment: I installed ImageMagick and ran identify -verbose on a screenshot that I edited with paint and saved as PNG, a haystack generated on windows, and a haystack generated on ubuntu. They seem to be very similar. [Selenium Screenshot with edit](http://pastebin.com/3Z5S9BH4) [Windows](http://pastebin.com/n5JSfFSn) [Ubuntu Haystack](http://pastebin.com/JNSZV0r8)

Comment: Yes no obvious difference. I'm guessing your respective browsers/OSes are rendering colors differently, then, so pixelwise compare can't work. You'll probably have to do the needle search using a more adaptable fuzzy algortihm, don't know if this is possible in opencv. See e.g. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/32276/why-does-my-hexadecimal-color-in-one-browser-render-differently-in-another-brows or https://fstoppers.com/education/how-your-web-browser-affects-way-colors-are-rendered-77241 or https://css-tricks.com/color-rendering-difference-firefox-vs-safari/

Comment: Hah, I wasn't aware of color rendering differences... with that in mind, I ended up deriving needles from the Ubuntu haystack and it worked, so for now I'll stick with an OS dependent solution until I can implement something better. Thanks for all of your help! :)

Comment: Ah, I was going to suggest that next. Hopefully you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different browsers (and probably OS/Window Manager) implement colour rendering differently - so the displayed pixel values may have different intensities of the R, G, B values which are invisible to the human eye but which make cross-platform pixelwise comparison of screenshots between browsers/platforms ineffective.